# How to split a date range into chunks of 3 days using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to split a specific date range into chunks of 3 days to find the number of records per each three day chunks.

For example, assume I have this table:

| User | Minimum Date | Maximum Date | Consecutive Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09/20/2021 | 09/29/2021 | 10 |

And I want to produce this table:

| User | Minimum Date | Maximum Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09/20/2021 | 09/22/2021 |
| 1 | 09/23/2021 | 09/25/2021 |
| 1 | 09/26/2021 | 09/28/2021 |

The reason I ended it off there is because the remaining days are not enough to make up 3 days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need in something like

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( 
    SELECT User, 
           MinimumDate, 
           MinimumDate + INTERVAL 2 DAY MaximumDate,  -- N-1
           MaximumDate FinalDate
    FROM sourcetable
    WHERE MinimumDate + INTERVAL 2 DAY <= MaximumDate -- N-1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT User,
           MinimumDate + INTERVAL 3 DAY,              -- N
           MinimumDate + INTERVAL 5 DAY,              -- 2*N-1
           FinalDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE MinimumDate + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= FinalDate   -- 2*N-1
)
SELECT User,
       MinimumDate,
       MaximumDate
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

or (not tested)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT (MAX(DATEDIFF(MaximumDate, MinimumDate)) DIV 3) - 1 maxrange
          FROM sourcetable ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT 0 num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT num + 1 FROM cte2 WHERE num < maxrange )
SELECT User,
       MinimumDate + INTERVAL 3 * num DAY MinimumDate,
       MinimumDate + INTERVAL 2 + 3 * num DAY MaximumDate 
FROM sourcetable
JOIN cte2 ON MinimumDate + INTERVAL 3 * num DAY <= MaximumDate
ORDER by 1,2
```

Comment: Just a quick question however, if we wanted chunks of 7 days instead of 3 days, where would we modify?

Comment: @TryingToLearn97 Updated, see comments.

Comment: @TryingToLearn97 Test alternative variant also.